# How i can print the answer and not the error of the post request?

Tags: android, api, post, kotlin, request

I send json and header to an API and I suppose to get back this on my response json :

```
{
  "email": [
    "is already taken"
  ]
}
```

> but I get a type of error like com.android.volley.ClientError

How can i get the json ?

```
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

    queue.add(accessTokenRequest)
        }
        val accessTokenRequest: JsonObjectRequest = object : JsonObjectRequest(
            Method.POST, url, JSONObject(json),
            Response.Listener<JSONObject> {response ->
                textView.text = "Response is 0-0' : $response \n et le truc envoyé is $json"
            },  Response.ErrorListener {response ->
                textView.text = " KO :( : $response \n et le truc envoyé is $json" }) {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
                var params: MutableMap<String, String> = super.getHeaders()
                    params = HashMap()
               // Log.d("TAGomago", "22$params 22")

                params["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                params["Authorization"] = "Bearer c87627e164190330138103cdab884c8d982bed7df8d23c30562c3bbb93239f13"
                Log.d("TAGomago", "22$params 22")

                //textView.text = " KO :( : \n et le truc envoyé is $json"
                return params
            }
        }
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

        queue.add(accessTokenRequest)
```

Comment: where does it show `com.android.volley.ClientError`? show the stacktrace.

Comment: the stacktrace is this 
2019-07-02 09:39:10.391 15132-15254/com.example.testapi E/Volley: [13339] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 422 for https://develop.api.live
??

Comment: 422 is the normal code when i send an email already taken